# NSFormatter nil dateFromString

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

My formatter returns nil with some date strings, it depends how the string is build. I suspect a problem with the timezone or something like that.

My formatter :

```
 let formatter : NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
 formatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd'T'hhmmss"
 let departureDate = formatter.dateFromString(departureDateString)
```

The string I want to parse : 20160508T150000 -> I get nil

Check debug results below :

```
po formatter.dateFromString("20160508T100000")
▿ Optional<NSDate>
  - Some : 2016-05-08 08:00:00 +0000

(lldb) po formatter.dateFromString("20160508T110000")
▿ Optional<NSDate>
  - Some : 2016-05-08 09:00:00 +0000

(lldb) po formatter.dateFromString("20160508T120000")
▿ Optional<NSDate>
  - Some : 2016-05-07 22:00:00 +0000

(lldb) po formatter.dateFromString("20160508T130000")
nil
```

What i'm doing wrong ? Need to specify timezone ? 
thanks

Comment: ~I'm stumped. This is very strange. Only thing I can imagine, it has something to do with hours past noon.~ @vadian figured it out :)

Answer (score 2):

...**15**0000 is 24 hour mode therefore it must be capital `H`

```
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss"
```

Comment: Arf, I didn't know that, thank you very much.